# Add virtual bridge without the loss of networking?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, kvm, bridge

There is a dedicated server without KVM-over-IP support.
The server 'owns' two IP addresses, and one of those is used for `eth0` at the moment.

The user needs to add a virtual bridge,  in order to use the second IP in a KVM guest.
All seems to be easy and straightforward - except most tutorials tell me that I should 'delete' the default ethernet connection. Which is just not that simple.

**The main question is in the subject, and the question covers a generic use case.

User wants a virtual machine entirely exposed - without NAT - and with a new IP.**

Comment: Additional info: Host is Ubuntu 15.04 - but it's not an OS-specific question; I have tried to use virt-manager to set up the bridge without loss of network ... it didn't work. Either I had an XML error if I tried to use eth0 as source, or a network that didn't work if I selected virbr0 interface (that I have set up in /etc/network/interfaces.)

Comment: Additional info #2: I can boot up a rescue disc from the DVD drive and edit networking from there. But I can do as much from the live system too, and then issue a reboot. (For example I can edit /etc/network/interfaces, and then restart the service.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With KVM (but not Xen) [you can now use Macvtap instead of bridging](https://wiki.math.cmu.edu/iki/wiki/tips/20140303-kvm-macvtap.html). So you don't actually have to tear down the host's network stack and bring it back up with a bridge.

Macvtap works by piggybacking on an existing ethernet interface. It will make your ethernet interface listen on an additional MAC address and it will "steal" the incoming packets addresses to that MAC address so they don't appear to enter through that ethernet interface anymore and instead go to the guest.

If you still want to use a bridging config, you can do it, and of course you realize, it's risky. One way would be to put all of the commands you need to execute to convert the configuration (`brtcl`, `ip`, etc...) into a shell script. Schedule an `at` job to reboot the machine 10 minutes later, then execute the shell script. If it succeeds, cancel the `at` job, and edit config files to make your changes permanent. If you make a mistake, at least you will get your server back 10 minutes later. I don't recommend it!

Comment: Sounds great, will give it a try today. Cheers!

Comment: Alright, so I added a NAT + macvtap (VEPA) interface to the guest via virt-manager. But how do I set the IP/network details? Should I set these in the guest? (**Because now, the guest DOES have the proper settings - which it should use - in the /etc/network/interfaces file. But there is no internet access in the guest, I cannot ping anything. Any ideas?**)

Comment: http://a.uguu.se/jdapmu.jpg < The VM. On the HOST, now I have `eth0`, `lo`, `macvtap0`, and `virbr0`. Should I remove bridge-utils?  As I said the guest contains every bit except the nameservers, but I cannot ping IP addresses either.

Comment: One last bit of info: **I do NOT need to reach the guest from the host. If the guest is reachable from outside via it's external IP, I am all settled.**

Comment: `virbr0` sounds like it is superfluous, leftover from a previous bridging configuration. Yet if it contains no ports (`brctl show virbr0`) then it will do no harm either. As for the macvtap configuration, I have used it before and it should work, but I also don't have a ton of experience with it nor access to a system that uses it right now so I'm afraid I don't have any ideas. What you're saying about your settings in the guest sounds all correct...

Comment: http://pastebin.com/QgcrrGAE < All I could gather. Oh, and there is no internet in the other guest where I did have connection before (with NAT). Things are getting better and better. :)) || Fun fact: If I try to remove "bridge-utils" it wants to remove libvirt-bin. ...

Comment: I have accecpted your answer, because it IS correct, and a working solution. I will fix my broken setup once I have the time.

Answer (score 2):

There are (at least) two different concepts here, routed vs. bridged setups.

If by virtual bridge you mean one that does not have `eth0` (or any NIC) as bridge port, you're looking at a routed setup where you don't have to delete the default configuration for `eth0`, but you have to set the proper routes for everything.

In a bridged setup on the other hand, `eth0` is part of the bridge, so you have to configure the bridge instead of `eth0` since `eth0` no longer functions independently, the bridge takes over.

Most datacenters provide their own documentation in regards to their specific environment. A bridged setup sometimes involves each IP having its own MAC address. So it also depends on how the IP is configured on their end.